# Spring JPA inserts duplicate select columns when using @MapsId, @AttributeOverride on embedded composite key

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm developing a Spring Boot REST API application and I've encountered a problem with SQL generation for Transact-SQL (SQL Server) dialect and I'm not sure where I did something wrong.

The application is about storage management and I have two entities: `Part` and `Stock`. I've simplified the structure to be as simple as possible.

I have composite PK - `PartPK`:

```
@Data @Embeddable 
class PartPK {

     @Column(name = "PART_ID")
     private String partId;

     @Column(name = "PART_ORGANIZATION_ID")
     private String orgId;

}
```

... and the entity `Part` having `PartPK` as `@EmbeddedId`:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "parts") 
class Part {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PartPK id;
}
```

then I'm having a `Stock` entity that ties to a `Part` entity and stores. The entity has a composite PK with the following structure, where I'm overriding attributes from `PartPK` (giving them STOCK_ prefix)

```
 @Data @Embeddable 
 class StockPK {

     @Column(name = "STOCK_STORE_ID")
     private String storeId;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "partId", column = @Column(name = "STOCK_PART_ID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "orgId", column = @Column(name = "STOCK_PART_ORGANIZATION_ID")),
    })
    private PartPK partId;

}
```

... and enclosing `Stock` entity where I'm trying to reference the Part entity using `@MapsId`:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "stocks") 
class Stock {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StockPK id;

    @MapsId("partId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_PART_ID", referencedColumnName = "PART_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_PART_ORGANIZATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "PART_ORGANIZATION_ID"),
    })
    private Part part;

}
```

Which compiles, but after executing a query from the repository, it generates the following query:

```
select TOP (?) 
           stockdb0_.stock_part_organization_id as bis_part0_0_,
           stockdb0_.stock_store_id             as bis_stor3_0_,
           stockdb0_.stock_part_organization_id as bis_part5_0_,
           stockdb0_.stock_part_id              as bis_part6_0_
from stocks stockdb0_
```

As you can notice, for some reason it uses 2 times `stock_part_organization_id` column. The entity has incorrect values after persistence mapping (two Stock rows having the same Store but different parts are considered to be the same entity). When the `part` attribute is removed from the `Stock` entity, the query and resulting persistence mapping is correct.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.5 (the latest) and Started Data Jpa of the same version.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `@IdClass` will work better in this case:

```
class StockPK implements Serializable {

  private String storeId;

  private Part part;

  ...
}

@Entity @Table(name = "stocks") 
@IdClass(StockPK.class)
class Stock {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_PART_ID", referencedColumnName = "PART_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_PART_ORGANIZATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "PART_ORGANIZATION_ID"),
    })
    private Part part;

    ...
}
```

But if you want to use `@EmbeddedId`:

```
@Embeddable
public static class StockPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_PART_ID", referencedColumnName = "PART_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_PART_ORGANIZATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "PART_ORGANIZATION_ID"),
    })
    private Part part;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_STORE_ID")
    private String storeId;


}

@Entity @Table(name = "stocks") 
class Stock {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StockPK id;
    
    // The association is already defined in the key
}
```

Anyway, you don't have to use `@MapsId` ([that's for something else](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived)) and you can find examples of both approaches with more details [in the Hibernate ORM documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite).

Comment: Thanks for response.(1) I want to avoid declaring the entity type inside composite PK as in specific situation I require just key atributes and that would fetch the whole entity when accessed. (2) The association is defined in StockPK, but I won't be able to intercept-fetch the Part entity from Stock entity and make Criteria queries based on non-key values of Part entity in Stock context.